# TLA+ Toolbox unexpected exception

Tags: tla+

I'm studying TLA+, and am running the lecture example code

```
EXTENDS Integers
VARIABLES i, pc

Init == (pc = "start") /\ (i = 0)

Pick == /\ pc = "start"
        /\ i' \in 0..1000
        /\ pc' = "middle"

Add1 == /\ pc = "middle"
        /\ i' = i + 1
        /\ pc' = "done"

Next == Pick \/ Add1
```

but I'm running into unexpected exception errors like

> unsuccessfully trying to load custom FPSet class: tlc2.tool.fp.OffHeapDiskFPSet
>   TLC threw an unexpected exception.
>   This was probably caused by an error in the spec or model.
>   See the User Output or TLC Console for clues to what happened.
>   The exception was a java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
>   : java.lang.NullPointerException

And User Output:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory.loadImplementation(FPSetFactory.java:206)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory.getFPSet(FPSetFactory.java:109)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.MultiFPSet.getNestedFPSets(MultiFPSet.java:68)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.MultiFPSet.<init>(MultiFPSet.java:61)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory.getFPSet(FPSetFactory.java:105)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory$1.call(FPSetFactory.java:136)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory$1.call(FPSetFactory.java:1)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.unsupported/sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Unknown Source)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.LongArray.<init>(LongArray.java:79)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.OffHeapDiskFPSet.<init>(OffHeapDiskFPSet.java:138)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory.loadImplementation(FPSetFactory.java:206)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory.getFPSet(FPSetFactory.java:109)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.MultiFPSet.getNestedFPSets(MultiFPSet.java:68)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.MultiFPSet.<init>(MultiFPSet.java:61)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory.getFPSet(FPSetFactory.java:105)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory$1.call(FPSetFactory.java:136)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.FPSetFactory$1.call(FPSetFactory.java:1)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.unsupported/sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Unknown Source)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.LongArray.<init>(LongArray.java:79)
    at tlc2.tool.fp.OffHeapDiskFPSet.<init>(OffHeapDiskFPSet.java:138)
    ... 15 more
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

update:
[image: TLC option]

TLA+ toolbox version:

```
 This is Version 1.6.0 of 10 July 2019 and includes:
  - SANY Version 2.1 of 23 July 2017
  - TLC Version 2.14 of 10 July 2019
  - PlusCal Version 1.9 of 10 July 2019
  - TLATeX Version 1.0 of 20 September 2017
```

Comment: What is your model configuration?

Comment: @AntonTrunov it's default. With deadlock checked. Thant's all I can see.

Comment: @drerD What are the settings on the "Advanced options" tab/page?

Comment: @M.K. I updated question with an image showing the options.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce it. This is what I'm using: "TLA+ Toolbox provides a user interface for TLA+ Tools. 
This is Version 1.6.0 of 10 July 2019 and includes:
  - SANY Version 2.1 of 23 July 2017
OS: Mac OS X, v.10.14.6, x86_64 / cocoa
Java version: 11.0.3"

Comment: @AntonTrunov I updated the question with my verison, and I think we have the same TLA+ version. I am running in Windows 10 with latest Java.

Comment: Could it be that TLC makes your machine run out of memory as the error message suggests?

Comment: The stack trace shows that the exception occurs at startup.  Please paste the TLC command-line that the Toolbox creates.  You find it in ~/.tlaplus/.metadata/.log  By the way, I suggest to move this discussion over to https://github.com/tlaplus/tlaplus/issues as this is clearly a Toolbox/TLC bug.

Answer (score 0):

does your specification file begins with a module line?
That is:

------------------------------- MODULE MySpec -------------------------------

if the file is MySpec.tla.

With this I could perform model-checking <>(pc = "done") using TLC both in the TLA+ toolbox version 1.6.1 and with TLC 2.14 from tla2tools.jar (command line). Nb: it fails due to stuttering.